# Use same functions over different arrays in Angular directive

Tags: angularjs

I'm really new to AngularJS and I'm having difficulties when trying to reuse functions over different arrays,actually its just one array and it has 2 more inside him.Can anyone tell me where I'm wrong,please.Thank you.

```
<body ng-controller="MainCtrl as mainCtrl">

<my-dates ng-repeat="item in mainCtrl.list"></my-dates>

</body>

app.directive('myDates', function() {
    return {
       // scope:{options:'&'},
        restrict:'E',
         template:'<table class="myTable">' +
        '<tr>'+
        '<th><input type="checkbox" ng-model="selectedAll"  ng-click="mainCtrl.checkAll()"></th>'+
        '<th>Start Date:</th>'+
    '<th>End Date:</th>'+
    '<th>Hours:</th>'+
    '<th>Status:</th>'+
    '</tr>'+
    '<tr ng-repeat = "items in item">'+
        '<td><input type="checkbox" ng-model="items.selected"></td>'+
        '<td>{{items.start}}</td>'+
    '<td>{{items.end}}</td>'+
    '<td>{{items.hours}}</td>'+
     '<td>{{items.selected}}</td>'+
    '</tr>'+
    '</table>'+
    '<button class="myButton" ng-click="mainCtrl.add()">Add element</button>'+
    '<button class="myButton" ng-click="mainCtrl.remove()">Remove element</button>'
    }
});

app.controller('MainCtrl', function ($scope, $modal ,$log) {
    var self = this;
    self.list = [[{start:1,end:15,hours:7,selected: false},{start:2,end:14,hours:6,selected: false},{start:3,end:13,hours:5,selected: false},{start:1,end:15,hours:7,selected: false},{start:2,end:14,hours:6,selected: false},{start:3,end:13,hours:5,selected: false}],
        [{start:1,end:15,hours:7,selected: false},{start:1,end:15,hours:7,selected: false}]];
    self.allSelected = false;
    self.add = function () {
        var modalInstance = $modal.open({
            template:  '<div class="modal-header"><h1>Add element to array</h1></div>'+
        '<div class="modal-body">'+

            '<div>'+
            '<span>Enter Start Date:</span>'+
        '<input  ng-model="object.start" type="text"/>'+
            '</div>'+

            '<div>'+
            '<span>Enter End Date:</span>'+
        '<input ng-model="object.end" type="text"/>'+
            '</div>'+

            '<div>'+
            '<span>Enter Work Hours:</span>'+
        '<input ng-model="object.hours" type="text"/>'+
            '</div>'+

            '</div>'+
            '<div class="modal-footer">'+
            '<button class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="ok()">OK</button>'+
            '<button class="btn btn-warning" type="button" ng-click="close()">Cancel</button>'+
            '</div>',
            controller: 'PopupCont',
            resolve: {
                items: function () {
                    return $scope.items;
                }
            }
        });
        modalInstance.result.then(function (object) {
            self.list.push(object);
        }, function () {
            $log.info('Modal dismissed at: ' + new Date());
        });
    }
    self.remove = function() {
        console.log('tc');
        self.list = self.list.filter(
            function(item) {
                return !item.selected
            }
        );
    }
    self.checkAll = function(){
        if ($scope.selectedAll) {
            $scope.selectedAll = true;
        } else {
            $scope.selectedAll = false;
        }
        angular.forEach(self.list, function(item) {
            item.selected = $scope.selectedAll;
        });
    }
});
app.controller('PopupCont', ['$scope','$modalInstance',function ($scope, $modalInstance) {
    $scope.object = {start:undefined,end:undefined,hours:undefined};
    $scope.ok = function () {
        $modalInstance.close($scope.object);
    };
    $scope.close = function () {
        $modalInstance.dismiss('cancel');
    }

}]);
```

Comment: please put the code in the question

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to do the following:

[Plunkr](https://plnkr.co/edit/ErwpBe)

At the moment your code doesn't know which list to select, so a couple of changes:

```
    '<button class="myButton" ng-click="mainCtrl.add($index)">Add element</button>'+
    '<button class="myButton" ng-click="mainCtrl.remove($index)">Remove element</button>

'
```

Then in the add:

```
self.add = function (index) {
```

refer to the index:

```
    modalInstance.result.then(function (object) {
      console.log(object)
        self.list[index].push(object);
    }, function () {
        $log.info('Modal dismissed at: ' + new Date());
    });
```

And also in the remove:

```
self.remove = function(index) {
    console.log('tc');
    self.list[index] = self.list[index].filter(
        function(item) {
            return !item.selected
        }
    );
```

Is that what you want?

Comment: I solved my problem.I removed all of the functions in the directive's controller and changed list to item which is my sub-array.Is that  a good approach to the problem ?

Comment: Its equally good, I'm not sure what the Angular stylists would say. If its less code and neat, then yes, its better.  Plus if it can be reused on another list or application, then even better.